# Compare 2 Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem to compare values in my javascript, here is the code :

```
     if(removeComma(f.txt_minTransFee.value) >= removeComma(f.txt_maxTransFee.value)){
         alert("MINIMUM TRANSFER FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM TRANSFER FEE");
         return;
     }
     if(removeComma(f.txt_minExFee.value) >= removeComma(f.txt_maxExFee.value)){
         alert("MINIMUM EXPRESS FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EXPRESS FEE");
         return;
     }
     if(removeComma(f.txt_minEarsFee.value) >= removeComma(f.txt_maxEarsFee.value)){
         alert("MINIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE");
         return;
     }
```

I tried the values are :

```
txt_minTransFee = 1 and txt_maxTransFee = 22
txt_minExFee = 2 and txt_maxExFee = 22
txt_minEarsFee = 3 and txt_maxEarsFee = 22
```

But the problem is cannot pass from 3rd function, its always alert 
"MINIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE"

Comment: What's removeComma() ?

Comment: `console.log` the values before the if statements and see what the values are being compared.

Comment: You're comparing text instead of numbers.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt: Or better yet, use the fully-featured debugger built into the browser. No need for stumbling about with a `console.log` torch when you can turn on the lights. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, parse your strings to numbers, handling errors for invalid input. Then, compare numbers.

```
 var minTransFee = +removeComma(f.txt_minTransFee.value);
 var maxTransFee = +removeComma(f.txt_maxTransFee.value);
 var minExFee = +removeComma(f.txt_minExFee.value);
 var maxExFee = +removeComma(f.txt_maxExFee.value);
 var minEarsFee = +removeComma(f.txt_minEarsFee.value);
 var maxEarsFee = +removeComma(f.txt_maxEarsFee.value);

 if (isNaN(minTransFee) ||
     isNaN(maxTransFee) || 
     isNaN(minExFee) || 
     isNaN(maxExFee) || 
     isNaN(minEarsFee) || 
     isNaN(maxEarsFee)) {
     // Handle the error, an invalid number was input
     return;
 }

 if (minTransFee >= maxTransFee) {
     alert("MINIMUM TRANSFER FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM TRANSFER FEE");
     return;
 }
 if (minExFee >= maxExFee) {
     alert("MINIMUM EXPRESS FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EXPRESS FEE");
     return;
 }
 if (minEarsFee >= maxEarsFee) {
     alert("MINIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE");
     return;
 }
```

**Note**: The above will treat `""` as `0`. If you don't want that, you need to check the strings for `""` before converting to number via `+`.

Alternately: Whenever you have repetitive code like that, think in terms of factoring the common parts into a function:

```
function checkMinMax(f, type, msg) {
     var minFeeStr = removeComma(f["txt_min" + type + "Fee]".value.trim());
     var maxFeeStr = removeComma(f["txt_max" + type + "Fee]".value.trim());
     var minFee = +minFeeStr;
     var maxFee = +maxFeeStr;

     if (!minFeeStr || !maxFeeStr || isNaN(minFee) || isNaN(maxFee)) {
         // One of them was blank or invalid
         // Show message
         return false;
     }

     if (minFee >= maxFee) {
         alert(msg);
         return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

...which we can then use like this:

```
 if (!checkMinMax(f, "Trans", "MINIMUM TRANSFER FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM TRANSFER FEE") ||
     !checkMinMax(f, "Ex", "MINIMUM EXPRESS FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EXPRESS FEE") ||
     !checkMinMax(f, "Ears", "MINIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE MUST BE LESS THAN MAXIMUM EARLY SETTLEMENT FEE")) {
     return;
 }
```

Note that that version checks for the `""` and considers them invalid.